# Reasonable filename characters?

Tags: filesystems, standards, filenames, portability

Is anybody aware of a list of reasonable filename characters? With *reasonable* I mean something like

- Do not use invisible characters with the exception of space (no tabs, no new lines, no right-to-left mark...)
- Do not use punctuation other than `-`, `_`, `.`

Essentially I want to ensure being as portable as possible between different filesystems without restricting myself to something like [8.3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename)

Comment: From what I can tell, the solution seems to be in the question itself. Just add a "You are allowed to use alphabets and numerical digits" and you would have something good enough. However, you would need to be more precise than "as portable as possible", if you want a more precise answer.

Comment: @JayBosamiya I could of course come up with a scheme fulfilling my own constraints but I'm asking for some kind of publicly accepted standard on how to name files